# No response from Amadeus Sandbox API - internal error reported

Tags: sandbox, amadeus

Amadeus Sandbox Server is not responding on API call.

The error which is getting displayed:

> An internal error has occurred. Please retry your request

Is this temporary issue affecting many?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the status of an off-site server and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of which "Sandbox" you are talking about, next time please add an example of the API call you are doing.

So far, I checked the [Amadeus Travel Innovation Sandbox](https://sandbox.amadeus.com) and [Amadeus for Developers](http://developers.amadeus.com) and both platforms are working well.